# Response headers of previous request affecting current request

Tags: node.js, express

The following code is the user-facing part of a new node app we are building:

```
var loadInvoice = function(req, res, next) {
    Invoice.findById(req.params.invoiceId, function (err, invoice) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(404, 'Page not found');
        } else {    
            req.invoice = invoice;
            next();
        }
    });
};

app.namespace('/invoices/:invoiceId', loadInvoice, function () {

    app.get('', function(req, res){
        var templateVals = {
            //some template data
        };
        res.render('paymentselection', templateVals);
    });

    app.post('', function(req, res){
        var data = {
            // some data for the apiCall
        };

        someAPI.someRequest(data, function(err, data) {
            console.log(res.status());
            res.redirect(data.url);
        });
    });

});
```

The first method returns a confirmation page where the user presses a button to post to the same url, which triggers a redirect to an external website.

This all works exactly once. Every second request will crash the app with the message Cant set headers after they are sent. After carefull inspection of the code I could find no reason for this to happen so I added the console.log line which indeed confirms the location header has been set. But it is set to the value i got from someAPI **on the previous request** not the current one.

This makes absolutely no sense to me. I do not store this value anywhere nor do I do caching or persistence of this data in any way.

Does anybody know what could be causing this?

I use express, express-namespace, mogoose and swig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem was being caused bij the 'Restler' libaray used within 'someAPI'. I have no idea how this is possible but swapping it out with something else fixed the problem.